# Lambda overload for Skip/Take Missing

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I was running some very simple test code to look at the effects of constants in linq queries and I'm having trouble locating an overload...

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx) specifically mentioned a lambda overload for skip/take, however I can not seem to locate it.

From Section 4.2 of [Performance Considerations for Entity Framework 4, 5, and 6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx):

> "In particular pay attention to the use of Skip and Take when doing paging. In EF6 these methods have a lambda overload that effectively makes the cached query plan reusable because EF can capture variables passed to these methods and translate them to SQLparameters."

They follow that with this code sample:

```
var customers = context.Customers.OrderBy(c => c.LastName);
for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    var currentCustomer = customers.Skip(() => i).FirstOrDefault();
    ProcessCustomer(currentCustomer);
}
```

My test code:

```
for(int i = 0; i<100; i++)
{
    var result = dc.Products
                 //.Select(p => p.Name)
                   .OrderBy(p => p.Name)
                   .Skip(() => i)
                   .ToList();
}
```

> Error: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'int' because it is not a delegate type

Am I failing at reading, or is there an include missing somewhere with the overloaded extension method? I'm on EF 6.1.1.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The extension method you're looking for is "[`QueryableExtensions.Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn344947.aspx)". It's in the `System.Data.Entity` namespace, in the EntityFramework assembly.

Comment: Fantastic - Thank you! My google skills were failing me on that one and I was starting to seriously second guess my reading skills. Will accept answer in a few - just waiting on the timer :)